# Exception while reading XML, DataSet.ReadXML, Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, xml, amazon-web-services, iis, strongly-typed-dataset

It occurs when multiple calls to read xml files using dataSet.ReadXML.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
 at System.Data.DataTable.NewRow(Int32 record)
   at System.Data.DataRowCollection.AddWithColumnEvents(Object[] values)
   at System.Data.XmlDataLoader.LoadTable(DataTable table, Boolean isNested)
   at System.Data.XmlDataLoader.LoadData(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Data.DataSet.ReadXml(XmlReader reader, XmlReadMode mode, Boolean denyResolving)
   at System.Data.DataSet.ReadXml(String fileName, XmlReadMode mode)
```

Comment: You can't read the dataset twice since the internal reader is at the end of file.

Comment: How to know that the internal reader has reached at the end of file. and block the concurrent file untill reached at the end of file.

Comment: The first the code is called it will open the file and read the entire file.  You can't call the code a second time unless the DataSet is disposed.  You have to have code to prevent the ReadXml() method being called twice.